# Find the difference between groups of binary strings based on index

Tags: python, pandas, byte, pandas-groupby

I'm wanting to parse some binary data in a column and show where bit errors are, and use that result to populate the values of a new column, showing these indices. E.g.

```
  id     type       bin
0  1    ERROR  01110010
1  1  CORRECT  11110000
2  1    ERROR  11101000
3  1    ERROR  11110001
4  2  CORRECT  00001111
5  2    ERROR  10100011
6  3  CORRECT  01010101
```

should be...

```
   id     type       bin        errors
 0  1    ERROR  01110010        [0, 6]
 1  1  CORRECT  11110000           NaN
 2  1    ERROR  11101000        [3, 4]
 3  1    ERROR  11110001           [7]
 4  2  CORRECT  00001111           NaN
 5  2    ERROR  10100011  [0, 2, 4, 5]
 6  3  CORRECT  01010101           NaN
```

I can find the bit errors, and do a groupby on the id, but I can't get thesevalues back into the 'errors' column above. All I get is the following...

```
   id     type       bin errors
 0  1    ERROR  01110010    NaN
 1  1  CORRECT  11110000    NaN
 2  1    ERROR  11101000    NaN
 3  1    ERROR  11110001    NaN
 4  2  CORRECT  00001111    NaN
 5  2    ERROR  10100011    NaN
 6  3  CORRECT  01010101    NaN
```

MWE:

```
def diff(a, b):
    return [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] != b[i]]

def find_errors(x):
    errors = []
    base = x.loc[x.type == 'CORRECT'].bin.values[0]
    crcs =  x.loc[x.type == 'ERROR'].bin.values
    for crc in crcs:
        e = diff(base, crc)
        errors.append(e)
    if not errors:
        return np.NaN
    else:
        print('Find errors: ', end='')
        print(errors)
        return errors

d1 = {'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3',],
      'type': ['ERROR', 'CORRECT', 'ERROR', 'ERROR',
               'CORRECT', 'ERROR',
               'CORRECT'],
      'bin': ['01110010', '11110000', '11101000', '11110001',
              '00001111', '10100011',
              '01010101']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

print("Before...")
print(df1)
df1['errors'] = df1.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda x: find_errors(x))
print("After...")
print(df1)

d2 = {'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3',],
      'type': ['ERROR', 'CORRECT', 'ERROR', 'ERROR',
               'CORRECT', 'ERROR',
               'CORRECT'],
      'bin': ['01110010', '11110000',, '11101000', '11110001',
              '00001111', '10100011',
              '01010101'],
      'errors': [np.NaN, ['0', '6'], ['3', '4'], ['7'],
                 np.NaN, ['0', '2', '4', '5'],
                 np.NaN]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
print("Goal...")
print(df2)
```

Comment: your error result doesn't really make sense to me - also your data doesn't match from input & expected output.

Comment: I've changed the expected output to match the input. What do you mean by error result? The bit indices? find_errors tries to compare 'CORRECT' binaries against 'ERROR' binaries, and shows the bit indices where each 'ERROR' binary differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is my approach**

I think you need create a Serie (**check_s** in my solution) where for each `id` there are the correct **bin** 
in all cells in order to compare and get the `Errors`. We can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) + `first`.
For this we have converted to `NaN` where an error occurs previously with [`series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html).
FInally, we use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and `apply(list)` to be able to compare the strings. We use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) 
to get the indices of the Errors and we add them to the list only if **m** is **True**(
**m** checks **where the series are different**, that is the errors).

```
check_s = ( df['bin'].where(df['type'].eq('CORRECT'))
                     .groupby(df['id'])
                     .transform('first').apply(list).explode() )

s =df['bin'].apply(list).explode()

m = s.ne(check_s)
df['Errors'] = ( m.groupby(level = 0).cumcount()
                                     .where(m)
                                     .dropna()
                                     .astype(int)
                                     .groupby(level = 0)
                                     .agg(list) )
print(df)

   id     type       bin        Errors
0   1  CORRECT  11110000           NaN
1   1    ERROR  01110010        [0, 6]
2   1    ERROR  11101000        [3, 4]
3   1    ERROR  11110001           [7]
4   2  CORRECT  00001111           NaN
5   2    ERROR  10100011  [0, 2, 4, 5]
6   3  CORRECT  01010101           NaN
```

**UPDATED**

If there are more than one bin correct for each id, we can should use this( **but this is slower, so it is better to use transform if this is not necessary**) :

```
check_s = ( df['bin'].where(df['type'].eq('CORRECT'))
                     .groupby(df['id'])
                     .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).apply(list).explode() )
```

Comment: Can 'first' on the transform be replaced to be able to find 'CORRECT'? I.e. if the correct packet isn't the first entry in the groupby?

Comment: check now:) 
as we have used series where previously this puts to NaN any place where type is different from CORRECT and when using transform ('first') the correct bin is correctly chosen for each id